# How to read and write values with binary files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable of type int and I wish to write it to a location within a binary file:

So something like this:

```
with open("file","wb") as f:
    f.seek(position)
    f.write(variable)
```

But the variable is to take 4 bytes at this position. How do I convey this when writing?

This is how I read:

```
def read(self, position, length):
    self.file.seek(position)
    a=self.file.read(length)
    data=0
    for i in range(length):
        data=data + (a[i])*pow(256,i)
    return data
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the Python [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct) module.  Example: `struct.pack("<I", 3)`

The example converts the integer value 3 as an unsigned integer, little-endian.

Here are functions to read and write native integers, using native size and alignment.

```
import struct

def write_int(f, position, x):
    f.seek(position)
    f.write(struct.pack("i", x))

_int_length = len(struct.pack("i", 0))  # find out size of native integer
def read_int(f, position):
    f.seek(position)
    return struct.unpack("i", f.read(_int_length))
```